# Linux: socket and binding issues

Tags: c, sockets

Which return value of the function close(socket) on the client side, the server get?
Everytime I close the connection from the client side my server closes as well and when I try to reopen it I got :
Error in bindind socket: Adddress Alreasy in use.

But I used this function in my server:

```
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (n < 0) errore("Errore lettura Socket");
if (n == 0) 
                  { 
int true = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int));
shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(sockfd);

}
```

Comment: It's usually the server that needs to set `SO_REUSEADDR`, not the client.

Comment: yes that is the code from the server side

Comment: the `setsockopt` call should be when you create the socket - it shouldn't be anywhere near where you're reading from the clients

Comment: and you appear to be closing `sockfd` not `newsockfd` - looks like this is a typo rather than an actual bug?

Comment: @Emperon in which case you need to call `setsockopt` _after_ the initial call to `socket` but _before_ the call to `bind`

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you!!! It works now!

Comment: Don't close the rendezvous socket (the one that you call bind() on.. keep that open on the server side.  Only close the socket that you get from accept().

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm still programming the server side, and everytime I close the program for recompiling and relaunch the server I need everytime to reboot the machine(binding error). it's frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

To allow rebinding to the same address, the `SO_REUSEADDR` option must be enabled on the server socket after it has been created, but *before* the `bind()` call is made, since it's that call to `bind` which actually attempts to attach the newly created socket to its intended IP address and port, i.e.

```
s = socket(...);
result = setsockopt(s, SO_REUSEADDR, ...);
result = bind(s, ...);
```